# Названия ягод

Tags: этимология

Всякие земляники, голубики и черники — это понятно. Но вот откуда взялась малина (от слова "малый"?), брусника и клюква?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**МАЛИНА**. Существует несколько объяснений этимологии этого слова. Так, допускается 
образование его с пом. суф. -ин-а (как рябина) от и.-е. корня *mel- > мал- со знач. цвета, окраски. Ему родственны: лтш. melns «черный»; лит. melsvas «синеватый»; лат. mulleus «красноватый». Другие полагают, что слово* малина*, возможно, образовано с суф. -ин-а от прил.* малый *«небольшой», поскольку ягода малины состоит из «малых» частей. Третьи 
считают, что соврем.* малина *развилось из древн* molina «малина», образованного от и.-е. *mol-/*mor-, и родственно лат. morum «ежевика», «тутовая ягода». (Цыганенко)

**БРУСНИКА**. Связано с *брус*, русск.-цслав. (о)брусити "гладить, точить", ст.-слав. *събрысати*, потому что спелые ягоды легко срываются. (Фасмер)

**КЛЮКВА**.  Некоторые исследователи возводят это слово к звукоподражанию *клюк* (ср. *клюкать*) -- от звука, издаваемого выжимаемыми ягодами. Родство с *клюкать* "шуметь"  допускает и другие исследователи, однако при этом видят в основе стар. название журавля; ср. *журавлиха* "клюква" (белор. журавіны "клюква"). Другие считают исходным знач. "болотная ягода" и сравнивают с *ключевина* "болото". (Фасмер)

Comment: Кстати, по-украински клюква — как раз "журавлина"

Comment: "ст.-слав. събрысати, потому что спелые ягоды легко срываются. (Фасмер)"
Ух ты! Не отсюда ли "брысь!" (сорвись?)
Как-то прикрикнула на 2-летнего сынишку: "Брысь с кухни! Ты мне мешаешь" Он твёрдо ответил: "Не брысю."

Comment: Хороший мальчишка.

Answer (score 0):

Обратим внимание на то, что плодоножка этой ягоды имеет характерный изгиб: 
https://berrys.guru/mestnye-yagody/gde-rastet-klyukva.html

Логичным будет предположение, что название ягоды «клюква» связано со словом клюка (клюшка), указывающем на отличительную черту ягоды – форму ее плодоножки.